# A question on extension of valuations / absolute values

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading "Fourier analysis on number fields" by Ramakrishnan and Valenza. Now I come to page 160: extension of absolute values. In the text the authors write: Let $K/L$ be a finite extension of global fields of degree $n$ (say number fields). Let $\mathscr{P}(K),\mathscr{P}(L)$ be the set of their places, respectively. An absolute value on $K$ gives rise to an absolute value on $L$ via restriction, so we obtain a map:

$r:=r_{K/L}:\mathscr{P}(K)\rightarrow \mathscr{P}(L), v\mapsto u.$

If $r(v)=u$, then $v$ is said to lie over $u$. And then there's a series propositions talking about the analysis of the fibers of this $r$.

What made me puzzled is: I've already known the basic fact on the extension of absolute values: i.e. the following theorem---If $K/L$ is an algebraic extension and $L$ is equipped with an absolute value $|\cdot|_K$, then there's a unique way to extend this extension to $K$, namely the formula $|\alpha|:=|N_{L/K}(\alpha)|_K,\forall \alpha \in L$. So I once thought that for an extension of number fields $L/K$ and a fixed place $u$ of $K$, there's a unique way to extend the absolute value to $(L,v)$ and obtain a unique extension of absolute values over local fields $L_v/K_u$. But according to the book I believe there's something wrong here: there are different places lying over $u$ in general.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my understanding of these two facts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you typed "extend this extension", did you mean "extend this absolute value"?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh you are right, I should write it more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the fact you are recalling, i.e. that $|\cdot|_K$ has a unique extension to $L$, applies when $K$ a **complete** valued field (or more generally a "henselian" valued field, but I suspect the former is where you saw it come up). So the comment will not apply to $K$ a global field.

Comment: Oh you are right! That's what I missed! The completeness condition is crucial! Thanks!

Comment: @tooweaktolearnmathematics good to hear! Please consider accepting the answer as well, it's best to have resolved issues off the "unanswered" queue

Comment: Ah, now I understood how to set this. I'm a new comer :) And sorry for forgetting to reply these days--I went to learn other subjects and forgot it! ^_^